# Load CSV file from S3 to RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, boto3, psycopg2

I am reading a file from the file system from loading data to PostgreSQL DB. I would like to use the code below to copy data to the database. However I have to fetch the CSV file from S3 instead of reading from the file system. I saw that there were utilities that allow data to be loaded directly from S3 to RDS - but it is not supported in my organization at the moment.How can I stream data from CSV file in S3 to PostgreSQL DB?

```
def load_data(conn, table_name, file_path):

    copy_sql = """
                   COPY %s FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
                   DELIMITER as ','
                   """

    cur = conn.cursor()

    f = open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql % table_name, file=f)
    f.close()
    cur.close()
```

Comment: A quick google led me to this page. Hope it helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Thanks @HaleemurAli.  I had gone over this link before posting this question. I was looking for an approach where I could stream data from S3 into the copy_expert command listed above. Due to org resrictions , I can only download and upload data from within my kubernetes pod.